# Surround string with quotes

Tags: php, string

Is there a function in PHP that adds quotes to a string?

like `"'".str."'"`

This is for a sql query with varchars. I searched a little, without result...

I do the following:

```
$id = "NULL";
$company_name = $_POST['company_name'];         
$country = $_POST['country'];
$chat_language = $_POST['chat_language'];
$contact_firstname = $_POST['contact_firstname'];
$contact_lastname = $_POST['contact_lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$tel_fix = $_POST['tel_fix'];
$tel_mob = $_POST['tel_mob'];       
$address = $_POST['address'];       
$rating = $_POST['rating'];

$company_name = "'".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($company_name))."'";
$country = "'".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($country))."'";
$chat_language = "'".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($chat_language))."'";
$contact_firstname = "'".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($contact_firstname))."'";
$contact_lastname = "'".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($contact_lastname))."'";
$email = "'".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($email))."'";
$tel_fix = "'".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($tel_fix))."'";
$tel_mob = "'".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($tel_mob))."'";
$address = "'".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($address))."'";
$rating = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($rating));

$array = array($id, $company_name, $country, $chat_language, $contact_firstname, 
$contact_lastname, $email, $tel_fix, $tel_mob, $address, $rating);
$values = implode(", ", $array);

$query = "insert into COMPANIES values(".$values.");";
```

Comment: General tip: always name each column that you're inserting values to, with just "insert into COMPANIES values(".$values.")" your query will break if you change structure of your table, or put the arguments in the wrong order, or don't put enough arguments.

Comment: This is a great resource for PDO : http://www.kitebird.com/articles/php-pdo.html
. And, I agree with the other posts here that prepared statements are in all respects a superior way to put together a query.

Comment: Don't use `stripslashes()` without checking magic quotes gpc setting. You can wrap this easily in a custom `get_string()` function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, I see you're using `stripslashes()`. That implies you have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) on. I would suggest turning that off.

What you might want to do is put some of this in a function:

```
function post($name, $string = true) {
  $ret = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST[$name]));
  return $string ? "'" . $ret . "'" : $ret;
}
```

and then:

```
$company_name = post('company_name');
```

All this does however is reduce the amount of boilerplate you have slightly.

Some have suggested using PDO or mysqli for this just so you can use prepared statements. While they can be useful it's certainly *not* necessary. You're escaping the fields so claims of vulnerability to SQL injection (at least in the case of this code) are misguided.

Lastly, I wouldn't construct a query this way. For one thing it's relying on columns in the companies table being of a particular type and order. It's far better to be explicit about this. I usually do this:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
// etc
$sql = <<<END
INSERT INTO companies
(name, country, chat_language)
VALUES
($name, $country, $language)
END;
```

That will sufficient for the task. You can of course investigate using either mysqli or PDO but it's not necessary.

Comment: It's not that the OP's code is vulnerable to SQL injection, it's that SQL injection isn't even an issue for prepared statement parameters.

Comment: a little "no filled" field problem appears here in insert `aValue, , otherValue`, but works

Answer (score 11):

Rather than inserting the value directly into the query, use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and parameters, which aren't vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html).

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT name,location FROM events WHERE date >= ?');
$query->execute(array($startDate));

$insertContact = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO companies (company_name, country, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ...)');
$insertContact->execute(array('SMERSH', 'USSR', ...));
```

Creating a PDO object (which also connects to the DB and is thus a counterpart to `mysql_connect`) is simple:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'user', 'passwd');
```

You shouldn't scatter this in every script where you want a DB connection. For one thing, it's more of a security risk. For another, your code will be more susceptible to typos. The solution addresses both issues: create a function or method that sets up the DB connection. For example:

```
function localDBconnect($dbName='...') {
    static $db = array();
    if (is_null($db[$dbName])) {
        $db[$dbName] = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbName", 'user', 'passwd');
        $db[$dbName]->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    return $db[$dbName];
}
```

If you're working with an array of more than two or three elements, you should use loops or array functions rather than a long sequence of similar statements, as is done in the sample code. For example, most of your sample can be replaced with:

```
$array = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
    $array[$key] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($val)) . "'";
}
```

Here's a more comprehensive example of creating an insert query. It's far from production ready, but it illustrates the basics.

```
$db = localDBconnect();

// map input fields to table fields
$fields = array(
  'company' => 'company_name',
  'country' => 'country',
  'lang' => 'chat_language',
  'fname' => 'contact_firstname',
  'lname' => 'contact_lastname',
  'email' => 'email',
  'land' => 'tel_fix',
  'mobile' => 'tel_mob',
  'addr' => 'address',
  'rating' => 'rating',
);
if ($missing = array_diff_key($fields, $_POST)) {
    // Form is missing some fields, or request doesn't come from the form.
    ...
} else {
    $registration = array_intersect_key($_POST, $fields);

    $stmt = 'INSERT INTO `dbname`.`Companies` (`' 
        . implode('`, `', $fields) . '`) VALUES (' 
        . implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($registration), '?')) . ')';
    try {
        $query = $db->prepare($stmt);
        $query->execute(array_values($registration));
    } catch (PDOException $exc) {
        // log an 
        error_log($exc);
        echo "An error occurred. It's been logged, and we'll look into it.";
    }
}
```

To make it production ready, the code should be refactored into functions or classes that hide everything database related from the rest of the code; this is called a "[data access layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer)". The use of `$fields` shows one way of writing code that will work for arbitrary table structures. Look up "[Model-View-Controller](http://www.google.com/search?q=PHP+model+view+controller)" architectures for more information. Also, validation should be performed.

Comment: how do you create your $db object? I tried it gives me `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in..`

Comment: did you click the link in the post? That blue text which says prepared statements?

Comment: @Marius: yes "blue text" :) I am novice in PHP, not in this forum :)

Comment: @outis. when connection I recieve: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost,dbname=mydbname'...`, however this works with `mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)`...

Comment: @serhio: change the comma in the DSN to semicolons (code has been updated to reflect this). This shows the value of reading the documentation (http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php)

Comment: apparently, the PDO was not installed on my hosting server, cause "not used". So, or PDO is something new, or not so popular.

Comment: The PDO extension shows up in the PHP source repository (http://cvs.php.net/viewvc.cgi/php-src/ext/pdo/pdo.c?revision=1.1&view=markup) 5 years, 9 months ago, back before version 5 was stable. At the time, it was primarily installed as a PECL extension. It shipped with PHP 5.1, roughly 4 1/2 years ago. The old mysql driver hasn't become deprecated yet, but it's not recommended by the PHP developers. If your server's PHP build doesn't include PDO, your host is quite behind the times. Also, if they don't offer it, of course it won't be used.

Answer (score 9):

Thought I'd contribute an option that answers the question of "Is there a function in PHP that adds quotes to a string?" - [yes, you can](https://eval.in/223292) use [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php), although it's probably easier to do it manually.

Benefits of doing it with this function are that you could also pass a character to wrap around the variable natively within PHP:

```
function str_wrap($string = '', $char = '"')
{
    return str_pad($string, strlen($string) + 2, $char, STR_PAD_BOTH);
}

echo str_wrap('hello world');      // "hello world"
echo str_wrap('hello world', '@'); // @hello world@
```

Answer (score 6):

Create your own.

```
function addQuotes($str){
    return "'$str'";
}
```

Comment: Or to make the function even better, add mysql_real_escape_string in it as well.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this. Instead use parametrized queries, such as those with [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: I am beginner, PDO is complex. How can I use PDO in my concrete situation (I added some code)? Thanks

Comment: outis's answer goes into a bit of low-level detail.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a function - but it's the first post that comes up on google when you type "php wrap string in quotes".  If someone just wants to wrap an existing string in quotes, without running it through a function first, here is the correct syntax:

```
echo $var   // hello

$var = '"'.$var.'"';

echo $var   // "hello"
```